# vscode extension iconPath

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on VSCode extension that uses `WebView` to show additional data. I works fine apart from the webview icon.

If nothing is specified the icon is:

[image: Default icon]

I was reading the documentation and noticed that `WebView` allow `iconPath` option with the following format:

[image: iconPath format]

I've tried to add the icon using the following code:

```
const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(
    path.join(context.extensionPath, 'resources', 'my-icon.svg')
);

panel.iconPath = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(onDiskPath);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Refused to load the image 'vscode-resource://file///f:/dev/my-extension/resources/my-icon.svg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https: data: blob: vscode-remote-resource:".

In the webview html the following content policy is avaialble:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
        content="default-src 'none'; img-src vscode-resource: https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
```

(i've tried messing with the content policies but nothing has changed. The same error is shown)

Is there a problem with the content policy or the way the icon path is generated? (or its something completely different :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a "webview URI" is for - it's for resources used *within* the webview. For `iconPath` you want a regular file URI, so it should be as simple as:

```ts
panel.iconPath = onDiskPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to provide some examples on top of Gama11's response.

The `panel.iconPath` takes a `vscode.Uri`. For example, if you have a `/resources` directory at the root of your extension with an icon called `icon.svg`, you could set it as the webview's icon like so:

```js
panel.iconPath = vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, "resources", "icon.svg");
```

You can also provide a dark and light version of the icon. Here's another example with 2 icons in a `/resources` directory:

```js
panel.iconPath = {
  dark: vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, "resources", "icon-dark.svg"),
  light: vscode.Uri.joinPath(context.extensionUri, "resources", "icon-light.svg"),
};
```